# ExpandableListView loosing data after scrolling - Android

Tags: android, expandablelistview

I am new to android and I am using expandable list view to show some data in parent and child layout. And each of child layout has one Edit Text. I am facing problem while inputting data into edit text.

**Scenario:**

I need to fill all the text fields and finally I need to click on save button to save the input.
But when I scroll my device screen I am loosing all the data that I have filled in the previous steps.

please someone suggest me how I can resolve this issue.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). If you want help about your code and layout please post the relevant code. Without code the problem is not reproducible.

Answer (score 1):

Save your edittext's in data in some collections like Hashmap. So that, you can fetch the values of edittext from hashmap while scrolling.

Comment: thanks Parul  for your quick response. But still I am in confusion that If I save the data in the collection, is it pops back the data in to edit text when I do scroll down?